# Form doesn't work stay on the same page when I click submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, c#-3.0

I am creating a feedback page, I want this page to go to sent page once I click the `submit` button. I have been trying this code, when I click `submit`, it just stays on the same page...

This is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Feedback", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = "Your Name"})
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, "Email", new {@class = "control-label col-sm-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email Address"}})
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Cell, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Cell, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = "Phone Number", type = "text"}})
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Message, new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = "Comments", rows = "4"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <button class="btn-raised btn-primary btn" id="submit">Submit
                <div class="ripple-container"></div>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Feedback()
{
     ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Feedback(FeedbackViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var item = new FeedbackViewModel()
                {
                    Name = model.Name,
                    Email = model.Email,
                    Cell = model.Cell,
                    Message = model.Message,
                };

        // TODO: Add success message to ViewBag / Data so notification will be displayed
        return RedirectToAction("Sent");
    }

    // TODO Send email in c#
    return View(model);
}
```

My model:

```
public class FeedbackViewModel
{
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public String Email { get; set; }

        [MinLength(10)]
        [StringLength(13, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid phone number")]
        public string Cell { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Please enter more than 20 characters and less than 200", MinimumLength = 20)]
        public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you hitting the controller's POST method (your button should be `type="submit"` or `<input type="submit" ... />`)? And if you are, then its because `ModelState` is not valid. And why do you have multiple `@Html.ValidationSummary()`? - it should be `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use **!ModelState.IsValid**, you must use **ModelState.IsValid**

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var item = new FeedbackViewModel()
            {
                Name = model.Name,
                Email = model.Email,
                Cell = model.Cell,
                Message = model.Message,
            };




            //TODO: Add success message to ViewBag / Data so notification will be displayed
            return RedirectToAction("Sent");

        }


        //TODOL Send email in c#
        return View(model);
```

Then add __ @Html.ValidationMessageFor(..)__  to view like that

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Feedback", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        @Html.ValidationSummary()
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = "Your Name"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, "Email", new {@class = "control-label col-sm-2"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Email, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email Address"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Cell, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Cell, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = "Phone Number", type = "text"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Cell)
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message, new {@class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Message, new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = "Comments", rows = "4"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <div class="btn-toolbar">
                           <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn-raised btn-primary btn" />
                           <button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
```